# Wrong Excel file opens in protective mode and changes to correct file once you click enable editing

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

We have a VBA process that extracts Excel files for different countries out of our Database.

Right now the issue occures that when opening any of these extracted files on Sharepoint it opens in protective mode and shows wrong data of a different country.
When you click on enable editing it switches to the correct file.

This also happens when sending this file via email to other people.

This is a big issue as this is sensitive data and each country should only see their own data.

It always shows the exact same "wrong" data of the same country in each of the opened files.

Comment: Maybe you should post the code.

Comment: @Foxfire and Burns And Burns I will see what I can produce as this code is fairly extensive and consists of many not so usefull query calls.

Comment: With the code, maybe SO can help. You don't need to post all code, start with the parts where you open the files, because your problem is opening those excel files.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns that is a good point. I was hoping this was maybe a simple issue with the protective view that someone encountered before, but I will produce a concise version of the code and post it here.